# All checkbox are checked upon clicking

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, input

I'm fairly new to react, and I'm trying to create a simple form. The form app has many elements including the 3 checkbox. And to simplify my issue, I'm only showing the checkboxes. Here what I'm doing

1. When I click on a checkbox, the value of the label will be pushed
   into an array and saved into the App state.
2. I'm using `event.target.name` because I have multiple inputs in the
   form and I wanted to keep just in case to make my problem more
   descriptive.
3. When I click on submit, it should clear the checkbox.

The problem is when I click on checkbox all the 3 of get checked and it won't be cleared after hitting submit. Is there any way to overcome this? or why its happening?

```js
function CheckBox(props) {
 var style= {
    padding:10,
    marginLeft:5
 }
  return(
    <div style={style} >
      {props.checkboxList.map((item,index) => 
        <div key={index}>
         <input type="checkbox" 
           onChange={props.changeHandler}
           checked={props.checkStatus} name={props.name} value={item.val} />
            <label>{item.num}) {item.val}</label>
        </div>)}

    </div>

    )
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={item:[],checked:false}
    this.changeHandler=this.changeHandler.bind(this)
    this.submitHandler=this.changeHandler.bind(this)
  }

changeHandler(event) {
  if(event.target.name=="choice") {    
  var arr=this.state.item.slice()
  arr.push(event.target.value)
  this.setState({item:arr, checked:event.target.checked}, ()=> console.log(this.state.item +"--"+ this.state.checked))
  }
  else{ console.log('error')}
}
  
 submitHandler(){
      this.setState({item:[],checked:false})
    }
  
render() {
  return(
  <div>
    <CheckBox  checkboxList={[
                {num:"a", val:"choice 1"},
                {num:"b", val:"choice 2"},
                {num:"c", val:"choice 3"}]} changeHandler={this.changeHandler} name="choice" checkStatus={this.state.checked} />
      <button onClick={this.submitHandler}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}
}
ReactDOM.render(
  
  <App/>,
  
  document.getElementById("root")

)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main approach is to add state key to the each checkbox:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={item:[],checked:{}}
    this.changeHandler=this.changeHandler.bind(this)
    this.submitHandler=this.submitHandler.bind(this)
  }

changeHandler(event) {
  if(event.target.name=="choice") {    
  var arr=this.state.item.slice()
  arr.push(event.target.value)
  this.setState({item:arr, checked:{
     ...this.state.checked,
     [event.target.value]: event.target.checked
 }}, ()=> console.log(this.state.item +"--"+ this.state.checked))
  }
  else{ console.log('error')}
}
 submitHandler(){
      this.setState({item:[],checked:{}})
    }
```

and for checkbox:

```
  {props.checkboxList.map((item,index) => 
    <div key={index}>
     <input type="checkbox" 
       onChange={props.changeHandler}
       checked={props.checkStatus[item.val]} name={props.name} value={item.val} />
        <label>{item.num}) {item.val}</label>
    </div>)}
```

Comment: It worked but the checkboxes aren't cleared after I click on submit.

Comment: @Nordax this.submitHandler=this.changeHandler.bind(this) just find and issue, should be  this.submitHandler=this.submitHandler.bind(this)

Comment: It worked on codepen, but not on my sublime project.it throws an error of not recognizing '...this.state.checked'. What does the dots in '...this.state.checked' mean?

Comment: It means that we pass 'checked' object to state, but change some keys. You can also do it via let newChecked = this.state.checked; newChecked[event.target.value] = event.target.checked;  this.setState({item:arr, checked: newChecked},

Comment: It works now. Thank you! I want to look into this type of state changing. Any documentations or just the right terminology to search on google would be appreciated. :)

Comment: It's a part of es6 or es7 syntax, called object spread operator.